# is there any meteor package to implement user status for custom user collection?

Tags: meteor

is there any meteor package to implement user status for custom user collection not default one. i implement "myUser" collection instead of default "meteor.user" collection and I want to add  status field to it?

Comment: is there any solution to Access my custom current userId on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a custom collection, just do this on server side:

```
export const myUser = new Mongo.Collection('myUser');

const userData = (userId) => {
  return myUser.find(userId);
}
```

You will now have an object with all of the user fields accessible on the server side.  To add a status field, on client just do a Meteor.call on every function that the user does.  (Click an event, submit to db, etc.)

```
Meteor.methods({
  'userOnline'(userId) {
     myUser.update({_id:userId},{$set:{onlineDate:new Date()}})
  }
}

Meteor.call('userOnline', userId);
```

Then query your db on what timeout you want. Last n seconds, minutes, hours.

```
query = {
    onlineDate: { // 18 minutes ago (from now)
        $gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 18)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any fields to the root of user object on server side, just make sure you subscribe to a publication on the client side like this one

```
/* eslint-disable prefer-arrow-callback */
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.publish('userExtraFields', function userExtraFields() {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find(
      { _id: this.userId },
      { fields: { currentTeamId: 1, teams: 1, isAdmin: 1, isCreator: 1 } }
    );
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. but i dont want to add custom field to the meteor.users.I have my user collection on external MongoDb and I want to detect witch user is online and store its status

Comment: Sorry there ^^
Maybe you are looking for this https://atmospherejs.com/konecty/user-presence

Comment: unfortunatly these packeges work with meteor.user collection

Comment: That's a normal Meteor pattern to have the users collection in an external MongoDB, you can store all of your data there